# angularjs http post to php method when we using oops

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using oops in PHP, I want to post data using angularjs to particular method, I searched many links and site i have not find any solution for that, can anyone solve my problem thanks.

this is my js script

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function FrmController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.msgs = [];

            $scope.SignUp = function() {

                $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);

                $http.post('post_es.php', {'uname': 'testName', 'pswd': 'testPass', 'email': 'testEmail'}
                ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data.msg != '')
                    {
                        $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously 
        if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    $scope.errors.push(status);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and this is php

```
<?php
     class sampleTest {
      public function firstMethod(){
       $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
      $usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname);
      $upswd = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pswd);
      $uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);
      }
     }
```

is it possible to post using post/get to a particular method

Answer (score 0):

you must first declare app and then declare your controller:

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function FrmController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.msgs = [];
            $scope.SignUp = function() {
                $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
                $http.post('post_es.php', {'uname': 'testName', 'pswd': 'testPass', 'email': 'testEmail'}
                ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data.msg != '')
                    {
                        $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously 
        if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    $scope.errors.push(status);
                });
            }
        });
```

you must link your app and controller by ng-app and ng-controller directives:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController